# at/on the edge of perishing

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction

**Australia's Great Barrier Reef is at/on the edge of perishing due to the massive rubbish released by local and international tourists, resulting urgent regulations to prevent things from getting worse.**

Q1. Are there rules about when to use "at the edge of" and "on the edge of"? What about in the above sentence?

Q2. Is "at/on the edge of perishing" correct? (I googled it but didn't see anyone write like this.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[*on the edge*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+edge) is an idiom. In your example:

> 1. In a precarious position; also, in a state of keen excitement, as from danger or risk. For example, "*When the stock market crashed, their whole future was on the edge*" or "*Skydivers obviously must enjoy living on the edge.*"

*at the edge* just indicates a location.
He was standing *at the edge* of the cliff